# What do I need to do to get my function to print out the new values for the nodes that i just scanned for?

Tags: c

I have a four initial values for my nodes. I created a scanf function that has allowed me to input four new values. Only problem is when I call my print function a second time the values have no changed. New to programming. appreciate the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

    struct node{
        int value;
        int values;
        struct node *next;
    };


void printLinkedList(struct node *thisNode){
    printf("The values in this list are: \n");
    while(thisNode != NULL){
            printf("%d\t", thisNode->value);
            thisNode = thisNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
    }


void scanNodes(struct node *thisNode){
    int value;
    int i;
    printf("Please enter the values of your nodes: \n");
    while(thisNode != NULL){
        scanf("%d", &value);
        thisNode = thisNode->next;
        i++;
        }

return;
 }



int main(){
    struct node n1, n2, n3, n4;
    n1.value = 1;
    n2.value = 2;
    n3.value = 3;
    n4.value = 4;

    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = &n4;
    n4.next = NULL;

    struct node *head = &n1;
    printLinkedList(head);
    scanNodes(head);
    printLinkedList(head);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You don't use `value` from scanf. Your previous question already get a working answer